# How disable gesture in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I`m using [Mutual Mobile Drawer Controller](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) to create a slide side menu, when i create the login screen and put as "is initial" shows first like as expected, but the menu works, I need  to disable de gesture for 3 viewsControllers, how can I do this :

[image]

This 3 views is the sing in and sing out, that can`t show the menu just when logged...

Answer (score 4):

You can see yours gestures with this and do whatever you want with them.
`self.view.gestureRecognizers`

Example that will remove all:
`self.view.gestureRecognizers?.removeAll()`

Comment: which method I need to call this ? viewdidload don't work

Comment: Try using it inside of viewDidAppear() this way it will always execute the code when the viewController appears. If you use inside of viewDidLoad() it can happen to just execute the code when the app loads the viewController for the first time, and this viewController can be used later again if you try to push it again but is possible that the app uses the one that was already loaded making it to do not pass again through viewDidLoad() but will always pass through viewDidAppear().

Answer (score 2):

```
drawerController?.openDrawerGestureModeMask = []
```