# Disable all gestures when work rotation gesture Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

How can I disable pinch and pan gestures when rotate UIImage in swift

Comment: [how-disable-gesture-in-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403640/how-disable-gesture-in-swift) same question

Answer (score 4):

for single gesture in uiView

yourgesture.isEnabled = false

for multiple gestures in uiView

```
for l in 0..<view.gestureRecognizers.count {
   view.gestureRecognizers![l].isEnabled = false
}
```